# Build:Cannot find type definition file for webpack-env

Tags: npm, webpack, visual-studio-2017, npm-install, azure-pipelines

we have a .net core Asp.net framework SPA. we performed below commands using Nuget package manager console on VS 2017. This would create all the node_modules stuff but while building the project it would throw error and fail "**Build:Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-env'**". It happens for few of us. For some it would happen randomly. We also tried to get node_modules on our build server using VSTS npm step and it would throw the same error. Any help?

1. npm init -y (to get/create package.json)
2. npm install

FYI: we have a webpack-env folder under @types folder

Comment: Can you show your project in one drive?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT unfortunately I can't share the project. However, if you wold like to see specific files or other details please let me know. FYI the scenario could be reproduced executing the above commands using npm or Nuget package manger console.

Comment: Can you add a example SPA project which build with the same error? And I have SPA project created by template (as the document mentions https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/), and has no such error.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT We will need to add/remove packages via npm package manager step in the VS build agent and try to resolve the dependencies manually. Other way around is to use the VSTS package manger add-on (a paid add-on to auto install packages using the above mentioned steps). VSTS package manager installs npm packages in a very specific way.

Comment: @JonnyBoy Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Bassie - Fortunately when Azure devops was updated (over time - this is an old post) the restore packages step in the build pipeline fixed this by itself we did not have to looks for a work around. This was a problem when VSTS was not fully migrated to Azure devops features with Dot Net Core.

Comment: @Bassie - new versions of visual studio have fixed these complications between VS 2019 - latest. And the modern Azure Pipeline are all equipped with such steps.

Answer (score 5):

Go to 'Dependencies' -> right click on 'npm' and click 'Restore Packages[image]

Comment: We are trying to build on the VSTS build server not using visual studio IDE. Thanks though.

Comment: Worked for me from VS2017. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We get this regularly when creating a project offline (no internet access at the time... Which happens all the time round here...).

We think its due to:
a) no "base" client (npm) packages in the base templates, so it MUST download these when created or first build, and;
b) some bug or bad config in the templates/VS/npm where if the project is built or attemplted to be built then it never tries to go get missing packages when it IS online...

We usually "just know this" and right click the projects "npm" widget and choose "update packages" or "install missing" (which is sometimes grey for us) but this usually kicks it into working again... obviuolsly need to rebuild again after this.

Occasionally this doesn't work so we close VS change the app.js file and reopen and then try the above again... so far this has fixed it for us.

Comment: We are trying to build on the VSTS build server not using visual studio IDE. Thanks though.